# Syntax error in creating a trigger in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I wrote a trigger which get trigered after update statement of table1. If there is no row in table1 based on the conditions, then update table2.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 
    AFTER UPDATE ON my_database.table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt int;
IF new.column1 = 1 THEN
   SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @cnt FROM my_database.table1 
   WHERE userID = 1 AND isDeleted = 0;
IF cnt = 0 THEN
   UPDATE my_database.table2 
   SET isDeleted = 1 
   WHERE userSeqID = new.userID;
END IF
```

It gives me error i nline number 4, I couldn't understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every IF statement has to ended with END IF clause. Try this statement -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON my_database.table1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE cnt int;
  IF NEW.column1 = 1 THEN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO cnt FROM my_database.table1 WHERE userID = 1 AND isDeleted = 0;

    IF cnt = 0 THEN
      UPDATE my_database.table2 SET isDeleted = 1 WHERE userSeqID = NEW.userID;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I want the second if statement inside the first if after the select statement.

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: Still it gives me same error at declare statement. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Note that you set @cnt variable in first SELECT, but use cnt variable.

Comment: I have no problems with this query. Pay attention at using DELIMITERS also. But firstly fix problems inside the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

The error on line 4 is because you're not using a delimiter.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger trigger1 after update on my_database.table1
for each row
begin
declare cnt int;
...
end if;
END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

You'll also need an `END IF` on the line after the `select` statement, and a terminal `END;` to match your `begin`, as I have in my example.